# Accessing form data from a jquery dialog when clicking on a button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

Please forgive Title - tough to explain

I am dragging a  to another droppable div.
The dropped span has a clickable object on it. When I click on it, the jquery dialog opens up.
I fill out the dialog with fields

When I click on another button, I get the number of objects in the droppable div.

Is there a way to access the data from the dialog via div objects?

Answer (score 0):

if it is a html form: yes you can do that using

```
$("#formId").serialize();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work.

I have a span <span>test</span>
I drag it on to a div $("#group")
I have an O on the span which I can click to open a dialog box
I fill out some fields
I have a button on the screen. When I get it, I count the number of spans on the div $("#group") and I want to get the dialogs fields based on what div(s) I dropped.
Make sense ?

Comment: may be you can pass on some fiddle link or so of what you are doing and then may be i can take a look